# ASP.NET and jQuery - Bulk Data Update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I am working with ASP.NET and jQuery, What I am trying to do is Bulk Data Updating on focus out (when someone tabs from one input field to another, update the data from the input field the user just tabbed out of)

Here is my HTML of one of the many rows:

```
<tr>
   <td><input type='text' name='ID' value='345924' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='carNo' value='1' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='BuyerName' value='Steve' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='BuyDate' value='3/15/2016' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='Description' value='Steve payment went through' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='amount' value='' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='payedSoFar' value='73501.71' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='lastPaid' value='2/19/2016' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='notified' value='s' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='notifiedDate' value='2/22/2016' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='issues' value='' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='issueDate' value='' /></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='Notes' value='' /></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my jQuery code with the focus out that calls the API to update:

```
$("input[type=text]").on("focusout", function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Action/updateCarInfo",
            type: "GET",
            error: function (request, status, error) {
            },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });

    });
```

and here is my ASP.NET API controller I am calling:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult updateCarInfo(int id, carClass cars)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != cars.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(cars).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

So my question is, how do I pass the data of the column I just tabbed out of and also pass the id from the first column? Or do I have to pass the entire row of data, even if it didn’t change?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val()` will give you the value of the field that triggered the     function, so that covers getting the appropriate field's value.

As for passing the ID, there are a number of ways to approach it. One way would be to use something like:

`$(this).closest("tr").find("input[name=ID]").val();`

This will traverse the DOM to the parent `tr` element, find the ID field within it, and provide its value.

Alternative for submitting the entire row:

```
<form action="/api/Action/updateCarInfo">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td><input type="text" name="ID" value="345924" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" data-id="345924" name="carNo" value="1" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="BuyerName" value="Steve" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="BuyDate" value="3/15/2016" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="Description" value="Steve payment went through" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="amount" value="" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="payedSoFar" value="73501.71" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="lastPaid" value="2/19/2016" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="notified" value="s" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="notifiedDate" value="2/22/2016" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="issues" value="" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="issueDate" value="" /></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="Notes" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

You can use `$(this).closest("form").submit()` to find the parent form for the row, and submit it.

Comment: Would you recommend this approach or would you recommend passing the full row?

Comment: For the amount of data that you're submitting, it's pretty standard fair to pass the whole row, in one go, but in that case, I would advise against using the `focusout` approach so as to avoid posting the full row for each field's focusout - instead opting to do a single post when the user is done editing a whole row.

Comment: I wish I could do that, but it was requested when they tap, they were using Access before, same sort of deal, row of input fields and when they hit tab it updates the data.

Comment: Access *cringe* bleh. That's fair - sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: so if I was going to save the whole row, how would I do that? Pass it as a class I guess

Comment: Easiest way would be to encapsulate each "row" in a form, and then submitting the form. The model binder will do all the magic of putting each value into the appropriate class properties (based on the property names that match the field names). Note, however, that simply placing `<form>` tags around `<tr>` elements is invalid HTML, so you should probably switch to `<div>`s or place each row in its own `<table>` and that table within form tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141386/discussion-between-sleeyuen-and-user979331).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the changed event. You only need to trigger this get when you have actually made changes to your data. I would also recommend assigning a class to the row, or inputs.

```
<table>
    <tr class='my-custom-class'>
       <td><input type="text" name="ID" value="345924" /></td>
       ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will allow you to handle your event at the row level.

```
$('.my-custom-class input').change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Action/updateCarInfo",
        type: "GET",
        data: $(this).parent().parent ().find('input').serialize(),
        error: function (request, status, error) {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```

I use the serialize method because we can serialize the entire row into a query string for your get request.

```
ID=345924&carNo=1&...
```

You can easily get the ID separately if you need to reorganize your data in the querystring. I only used serialize as this would make it easier but if it's incorrect for the controller method routing, do let me know.

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('data-id').attr('data-id');

//OR

var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name="carNo"]').data('id');
```

Let me know if there is a problem with this solution. Would be happy to accommodate.

Comment: This line does not grab the whole row

Comment: This does not grab the whole row `data: $(this).parent().find('input').serialize(),`

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Okay, I am able to grab the whole row, but when I try to pass it to my ASP.NET API Controller, I get null :(

Comment: What does your routing look like? Also where do you intend for it to bind the Id parameter? From the uri?

Comment: Also have you examined your ajax request? What does the response say?